# Strange behavior with the method getUploadedBlobs

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I've a problem with the methode blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(). I've a JSP page in wich one I set an uploader like this :

```
<formname='form'  action='<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/Edit_Engine") %>' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<input label='...' multiple='false' name='myFile' />
//...and multiple input for text
</form>
```

and I retrieve this code with my servlet :

```
java.util.Map<String,BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
BlobKey blobK  = blobs.get("myFiles[]"); //I don't know why I need to add the characters 's[]' at the end...
```

But the behavior is strange. The first time I upload an image, everything works. However, the second time, I send my form without uploading somehting (only text data), and then my java code finds a BlobKey. But this BlobKey seems to be the previous sended data, or a corrupted data.
I mean that not normal, because when I deploy this version on my localhost, if the form uploads no file the method getUploadedBlobs returns an empty HashMap. However, when I deploy on google servers, if the form uploads no file, the method getUploadedBlobs seems  to return a HashMap with wrong data.

Could you help me? Or tell me if this behaviro is normal...

Many thanks,

bat

Comment: I think that in all cases, if I send a form without file inside, google blobstore create an empty blob...

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a valid BlobKey, then `myFiles[]` is most likely the name given to the file input field in the form. Is that the case? That seems like an odd name for an input field. Are you using a template library to help generate HTML from the JSP?

Comment: yes, I use dojo for rendering the inputs and uploaders..So, you're right, dojo change the name I tkink so..